# Pitch Detection with the Histogram Frequencies Algorithm

Tags: matlab, pitch

i would like to ask...

is there such a thing such as "Pitch Detection with the Histogram Frequencies Algorithm" ?

Does such a thing exist or is it the harmonic product spectrum algorithm or cepstral algorithm for pitch detection ?

Also do you have more information on the algorithm and source code in matlab ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

A frequency histogram is often used as part of the explanation of the harmonic product spectrum method of pitch estimation.

A histogram that is a composite of several STFT frames over time may contain more of the harmonics of a note whose spectrum evolves over time (with various overtones appearing and/or disappearing, including even the fundamental), thus allowing a potentially more robust HPS estimation of the pitch.